# PHP in a JQuery Variable?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is anything like this possible?

```
var name = "<?php username_exists( $('input#register_name').val() ); ?>"
```

where

```
$('input#register_name').val()
```

is jquery code? So basically combining the two codes together so that PHP function is using that JQuery code?

Comment: Ajax and JSON are really easy to use. You should look into

Jquery `$.post` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ 
and 
PHP `json_encode` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: What I would like to know is, how are you posting the form data? To the same page?

Answer (score 3):

Not really.

1. PHP runs on the server.
2. It outputs some text.
3. The browser interprets that text as HTML/JavaScript

By the time you hit step 3, the PHP has finished.

If you want to pass data from JS to PHP you have to do so in a new HTTP request (via a link, form submission, Ajax, etc).

Comment: As I feared :( Really not good with this AJAX stuff. Trying to get it so that when my form is submitted, it checks that the username is not already registered and if it is then it displays a message. I can do it fine with just PHP but this refreshes the page. I don't want this to happen. I want just the message to appear.

Answer (score 1):

No, simple answer. Server side code cant operate on client side code directly. However with AJAX you can send jQuery data back to PHP

Like:

```
 var name = $('input#register_name').val();
 $.post('checkuser.php', { name: name }, function(data) {
      alert("Hey");
 });
```

Comment: Whats the { name: name } part?

Comment: @Tenatious First name is the data key $_POST['name'] that you can retrieve in your PHP script. Second is the input value sent from your jquery. Of course it looks a little funny but I wanted to use the same js variable as you did.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: no. You can use ajax to send PHP the value of the input and parse the response :).

In response to your comment above:

```
$('#my_input').blur(function() { // Change 'my_input' to ID of your input
    if ($(this).val() != '') { // Make sure it isn't blank to avoid unnecessary requests
        $.post('my_file.php', $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
            alert(response); // Variable 'response' contains response form php script
        });
    }
});
```